# Output the total number of String Characters

Tags: java

My Question is what method should I use if I wanted to get the total number of characters a user inputs? without using arrays, i tried using .length() but it did not return all characters say from the first and lastname, it only returned the first name.

Here's an example of my code. (Please dont laugh im really new in programming :) )

```
System.out.print("Enter your first and last name: ");
String yourName = keyboard.next();
System.out.println("Your name has a total of " + yourName.length() + " numbers");
```

what happened was if i enter say "Neo Matrix" it would only return 3.

I appreciate any help. thank you!

Comment: Is this homework, or are you doing this for "fun"? (I'm reminded of a proverb: give a man a program, and you frustrate him for a day. Teach a man to program, and you frustrate him for life.)

Comment: Which (fully-qualified, that is, how you imported it at the top of your file) type does the variable keyboard have?

Comment: The problem comes from the "keyboard" object. Its "next()" method probably gives you the next word of the input and not the global input text.

Could you explain what is this object?

Comment: @rajah9 - This program is for fun, I'm trying to create a Program called FLAMES for my sister. Basically i need the user to input their names then cancel out all the same letters then show results according to remaining letters. i know its a cheesy program but im just a newbie :D

Comment: That's great. Sort of like "SISTER" - "BROTHER" = "SIS"?

Comment: Correct then "SIS" would equal to 3 which in FLAMES given that F=1, L=2,and so on so 3 should be A which means Affection HAHHAHA! i know dude its crazy but my sister is happy :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `next()` only reads the first word of your name. Try `nextLine()` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! for some reason i didnt see it on eclipse when you ctrl+space it. i may have overlooked it.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read an entire line.

`next()` tokenizes the `String` according to the whitespaces, so you get only the first word - as expected.