# Why doesn't StringTokenizer understand the nextToken function?

Tags: java, variables, input, int, stringtokenizer

I made a calculator and now improving it so that it reads one line of code and turns it into three variables **a: first number,** **b: second number,** **and function: what it does** example: `10 * 10`. This is my code:

```
System.out.println("problem: ");
problem = user_input.next();
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(problem," ");
a = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
String Menu = (token.nextToken());
b = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
```

It doesn't understand nextToken at all, it says at `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at mycalc.main(mycalc.java:20)`,
 also I asked a friend that actually showed me how this works and he was confused too. Please help me any possible way you can!

Comment: `Unknown Source` means there isn't any debug information.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/23220224/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20104942/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147003/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20189486/1743880. Ha and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23968923/1743880...

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
problem = user_input.next();
```

this read just one word. e.g. if you input `10 * 10`, then this word will be `10`

So when you do

```
String Menu = (token.nextToken());
```

there is no such element as the error suggests.

Note: you are parsing for words two different ways.  It would be simpler to just use the scanner.

```
System.out.println("problem: ");
a = user_input.nextInt();
String menu = user_input.next();
b = user_input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Isn't StringTokenizer supposed to separate it into several groups between spaces?

Comment: @TheLittleCoder it does. however your input stream only has one word as `next()` only returns one word.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer duplicate questions as per the FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841. One should vote to close instead.

Comment: @Tunaki thank you for commenting. Though the duplicate doesn't explain why StringTokenizer shouldn't be used.

Comment: That would be a different question indeed. Which is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated?rq=1.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, although not that one. It talks about using split which wouldn't make sense in combination with Scanner when you want to split on space which is what Scanner does by default.

Comment: The point is, it would be a different question. The question here is solving the exception, which the duplicate (and the linked questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681062/why-doesnt-stringtokenizer-understand-the-nexttoken-function/36681128?noredirect=1#comment60952027_36681062)) answers. One should always search for duplicates before answering.

Comment: @Tunaki That is shallow interpretation of "Please help me any possible way you can" but we can agree to disagree.